# WinForms app connected to WCF via net.tcp fails with message netTcpWIndowsAuthentication rejected the session-establishment request

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, iis, tcp

This started yesterday shortly after the WCF host was built.  Here is the exception message:

[image]

When I looked at the nettcp connections I noticed there were 10 established.  The other strange thing I noticed was that there were quite a few connections in a "close wait" state.

The WCF binding is essentially all defaults, so I am wondering if we are reaching a threshold issue here or not.  This is the server bindings:

```
    <binding name="netTcpWindowsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="5461336" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
    </binding>
```

So I am wondering what the best way to go about recreating the issue in dev would be?  Set max number of connections to 0 or 1?  Given the defaults is it possible that connections are not timing out fast enough and we are exhausting the limit?

This issue seems to have gone away today.  But I am afraid to just continue using net.tcp without having a better understanding of what went wrong and how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case, our service was taking much longer than it should and the connections were piling up, even refusing new connections past the limit. Maybe using a fake service which blocks for a long enough time  (e.g. simply calling `Thread.Sleep(n * 1000)`) could help reproduce the issue on the client side, if this the case for you too.